# Does Thread.Sleep deactivates a TCPListener?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, tcp, tcplistener

I have a thread like this:

```
        Public Sub StartWork()
        Try
            myTCPListener.Start()
            While StopRequest = False
                Dim requestspending As Boolean = m_TCPListener.Pending()
                If myTCPListener.Pending = False Then
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                Else
                   DoSomething()
                End If

            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Now my question is: I send the Thread via Thread.Sleep to sleep mode when nothing happens here. Does this affect the TCPListener in his work somehow and what happens to an incomming connection while the Thread is in sleep-mode?

Comment: Yes.  The code is strange, you only DoSomething when somebody is trying to connect.  So don't bother, just call AcceptSocket instead so you don't have to sleep to avoid burning core.

Comment: the thing is that when i run it without thread.sleep the program takes 33% of my cpu (amd x6 phenom), with thread.sleep it just takes 17%. so when the thread sleeps connections still can pend, but can't be accepted, did i get that right?

Comment: Pretty unclear how you can burn 17% core with Thread.Sleep(100) calls.  Anyhoo, you should definitely prefer the 0% you get from AcceptSocket.

Answer (score 0):

While your thread is asleep it can't do anything. In particular it won't be able to accept a connection. So clients connecting to you will have to wait for 100ms until the connection gets established (the connection gets established when you call Accept and Accept returns).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim connection As Socket
Dim reader As BinaryReader
Dim writer As BinaryWriter
Dim socketStream As NetworkStream
Dim listener As TcpListener

Dim ip As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipstring)
listener = New TcpListener(ip, portnumber)
listener.Start()

connection = listener.AcceptSocket()
socketStream = New NetworkStream(connection)
writer = New BinaryWriter(socketStream)
reader = New BinaryReader(socketStream)
```

this is the efficient way to handle incomming connections :-), you dont have to put anything to sleep. If performance is an issure, decrease the priority of the thread. ex:

```
serverthread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

Listening for TCP connections and serving them is a standard design pattern. There is a better way to do it than you have in your code. Use `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()` which blocks until there is a connection request and when that happens it returns `TcpClient` you can work with to serve the client. Even though `AcceptTcpClinet()` is a blocking call (won't return until there is a request) it will not use CPU time. Since this is exactly what you do in your code (do nothing until there is a request) it will do the job you want.

Generally you should avoid `Thread.Sleep()` as it is not the best way of giving up CPU time. You should rather use specialized listening methods like `AcceptTcpClinet()`, timers, asynchronous calls, `WaitHandle`, `Thread.Join()` and so on. It is much harder to do and sometimes not worth it but that should be your aim.